# echo "\n" equivalent in python

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7

How to execute below command in python script.

`echo "\n" | sosreport #command to generate report in linux os.`

Thanks for all your efforts. sorry if my question not understanding.

I have achieved this by below code:

```
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE
p = Popen(['sosreport'], stdin=PIPE, shell=True)
p.communicate(input='\n')
```

Comment: `print('\n')` would do the trick

Comment: Just edited question, sorry for confustion

Answer (score 0):

You can use "print" fn to get a stdOut response.

Ex:

```
print("Hel\nlo")
```

output:

Hel

lo

```
print("Hello"); print("World");
```

output:

Hello

World

EDIT:

For sosreport, you can build a python script with one text parameter, and invoke that from linux OS. Example

```
echo sosreport | python yourScript.py
```

yourScript.py:

```
import sys
for line in sys.stdin:
    print line
```

Comment: @MrT, I you suggested edited question. Hope it fine. Please let me know if not correct format

Comment: Ignacio, Thanks a lot for your support. I have achieved it and same thing posted in question